# Loop through odd numbers and 2

Tags: c, loops

Is it possible in C to have a fast for/while loop that loops through the odd numbers and 2? Without using arrays.

So I'd like it to loop through {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, ..}

Comment: Loop through odd numbers. And make a special case for `2`. Or for `1` and `2` to make the special cases before the main loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah I had thought about that. But I was wondering if there possibly was a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: If by "elegant" you mean shorter - yes. But it will impact the readability and (arguable) the performance.

Answer (score 3):

Of course. Here is a pretty straight forward way.

```
for(int i=1; i<N; i++) {
    if(i>3) i++;
    // Code
}
```

A bit more hackish variant:

```
for(int i=1; i<N; i+=1+(i>2)) {
     // Code
}
```

But I think in this case that the most readable variant would be something like:

```
// Code for 1 and 2

// Then code for 3,5,7 ...
for(int i=3; i<N; i+=2) {
    // Code
}
```

Comment: and third considers odd numbers only. What are you suggesting?

Comment: @psinaught it suggests the iteration considers odd numbers, while `2` is a special case. If all the numbers are to be considered in sequence, `1` is also a special case because it comes before `2`.

Comment: @psinaught Roemerdt Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which does use an array but only a small one that is a constant size of two elements no matter how many numbers in the sequence would be:

```
{
    int i;
    int  iray[] = {1, 2};
    int n = 15;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i += iray[i > 2]) {
        printf (" i = %d \n", i);
        // code
    }
}
```

which produces:

```
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 5
i = 7
i = 9
i = 11
i = 13
```

**Extending this alternative to other sequences**

And this alternative can be extended to other sequences where there is a change of a similar nature. For instance if the desired sequence was

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11, ..
```

Which involves several changes in the sequence. Beginning at 1 an increment of 1 is used followed by a first increment change beginning at 3 where an increment of 2 is used followed by a second change in the sequence beginning at 5 where an increment of 3 is used, you can make the following modification.

```
{
    int i;
    int  iray[] = {1, 2, 3};  // increment changes
    int n = 15;

    // calculate the increment based on the current value of i
    for (i = 1; i < n; i += iray[(i > 2) + (i > 3)]) {
        printf (" i = %d \n", i);
        // code
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which would produce:

```
 i = 1
 i = 2
 i = 3
 i = 5
 i = 8
 i = 11
 i = 14
```

Comment: Could do the very same without array `for (i=1; i < n; i+= 1+(i>2))`

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes I know. However that is already been presented. this introduces the idea of using a logical operation as an array subscript which I thought interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
for(int i=1;;++i) // you didn't specify a limit
{
    switch(i)
    {
        default:
            if(!(i&1))continue;
        case 1:
        case 2:
            DoSomething(i):
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(unsigned x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    printf("%u%s element - %u\n",x + 1, !x ? "st" : x == 1 ? "nd" : x == 2 ? "rd" : "th", !x + x * 2 - (x >= 2));

    return 0;
}
```

no jumps calculating in the `!x + x * 2 - (x >= 2)` so no pipeline flushes.